# error creating Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

While creating one table in Hive I am getting this below error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   MetaException(message:Got exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied:
>   user=admin, access=WRITE, inode="/user":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:281)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:242)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:169)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:152)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6621)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6603)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6555)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:4350)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4320)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4293)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:869)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.mkdirs(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:323)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:608)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080) )

Answer (score 0):

You should read the log before posting here. Also it would be helpful to write the hive statement you tried.

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied:
>   user=admin, access=WRITE, inode="/user":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

means that you run the statement as a user(admin) with no authorization to write on the hive database. You should run the statement as another user or give user admin the rights to save on hive